# Informix SQL count() comparisons

Tags: sql, count, grouping, informix

I'm trying to build a SQL query that will count both the total number of rows for each id, and the number of 'FN%' and 'W%' grades grouped by id.  If those numbers are equal, then the student only has either all 'FN%' or all 'W%' or a combination of both.

**I need a list of all the id's who only have stats of 'FN%' or 'W%'**

example id # 683 & 657 would make it into the result set of the query, but 603, 781 & 694 would not

```
   id stat
  683 WF
  683 WF
  683 WF
  683 WF
  683 W
  683 W
  657 W
  657 W
  657 W
  657 W
  781 B+
  781 IP
  781 WP
  781 WP
  603 FN
  603 FN
  603 F
  603 FN
  603 FN
  694 B
  694 B+
  694 CI
  694 LAB
  694 WF
  694 WF
```

sample output:

683
657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions that I can think of. I'm not sure if they'll work in Informix:

```
SELECT  id
FROM    foo a
GROUP   BY id
HAVING  COUNT(*) = (
                SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    foo b
                WHERE   a.id = b.id
                AND     (b.stat LIKE 'FN%' OR b.stat LIKE 'W%')
        );
```

And if subqueries in the `HAVING` clause are verboten, maybe this will work instead:

```
SELECT  id
FROM    (
                SELECT  id, COUNT(*) stat_count
                FROM    foo
                WHERE   (stat LIKE 'FN%' OR stat LIKE 'W%')
                GROUP   BY id
        ) a
WHERE   stat_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo b WHERE a.id = b.id);
```

Update: I just tried these in Oracle, and both work.

Comment: Both queries work fine in Informix IDS 11.50.FC3W2 on Solaris 10.

Answer (score 0):

Where xxxx is the temp table that holds this info to be processed.....

```
select id, fullname, count(id) ttl 
from xxxx 
group by id, fullname 
into temp www with no log;


select id, fullname, count(id) ttl_f 
from xxxx 
where grd like 'FN%' or grd like 'W%' 
group by id, fullname 
into temp wwww with no log;


select www.id, www.fullname 
from www, wwww 
where www.id = wwww.id and www.ttl = wwww.ttl_f;
```

Comment: That's a long way to do it.  Where is the fullname coming from?

Answer (score 0):

That explanation makes my head hurt.  Are you looking for the union of these two sets?

- ids which only have stats matching "W%"
- ids which only have stats matching "FN%"

If that's the case, make it a UNION query with a sub-query for each of the sets.

Comment: i dont even like my own explanation either... i just had to find all the id's who had stats of only ('FN%' or 'W%')

Answer (score 0):

This was written against the original question:

```
select first 50
c.id,
(select trim(fullname) from entity where id = c.id) fullname,
count(*),
(select count(*) from courses where id = c.id and grd like 'FN%') FN,
(select count(*) from courses where id = c.id and grd like 'W%') W
from courses c
group by 1
```

The subquery to retrieve the name is much faster than using a join for some reason.

Edit:
The following will have the same behavior as yukondude's answer but performs better on our HPUX / Informix v10.00.HC5 box.

```
select c.id
from courses c
where not exists (
        select id
        from courses
        where (grd not like 'W%' and grd not like 'FN%')
        and id = c.id
)
group by 1
```

Comment: This produces more rows than required, and includes data that was not required, and references an undefined table...

Comment: It appears you are running Jenzabar CX - but I could be wrong. If you are, replace 'entity' with id_rec, and 'courses' with cw_rec.

Comment: No, you're right on.... thats creepy matt.  I didn't want to use real id's and fullnames for obvious reasons.

Comment: Your concat question was a dead giveaway. Email is in my profile if you have any CX specific questions.

Comment: oh from my other questions.... that makes sense

thanks... i'll definately put it in my address book